# Datepicker on Salesforce Visualforce pages,

Tags: apex, visualforce, form

Hello I'm currently doing a form on salesforce that will allow a customer to pick a deadline for the project that they ordered, And i want a datepicker for the `apex:inputfield`. I can do a datepicker using standard Html and js but when it comes to VF I'm a little bit lost. I've tried a lot of things and the latest one is I've put the input type outside of the `apex:inputField` but this is what it came up with.

```
<input type="text" id="datepicker">     
  <apex:inputField value="{!Service_Order__c.Project_Deadline__c}" html-placeholder="Please allow 8 weeks" id="datepicker" required="true" styleClass="form-control" />
</input>
```

[image: Calendar]
[image: calendars]

The second one shows where I need the calendar to appear inside of the apex input.

Comment: have you tried `<apex:inputField id="datepicker" value="{!Service_Order__c.Project_Deadline__c}" html-placeholder="Please allow 8 weeks" id="datepicker" required="true" styleClass="form-control" />` ?

Comment: @Ratan your suggestion includes two `id` attributes, both with the value of `datepicker`. This won't compile.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As this looks like jQueryUI's datepicker, the JavaScript below reflects that assumption.

The `<apex:inputField>` will render an input element. You don't need to wrap it with another one. The salesforce input element will be rendered to the page and have a dynamically generated ID value based on its location in the page hierarchy and will end with the value you've given it: `id="datepicker"`. The DOM id value will resemble something like this depending on the ids given to the datepicker's parent elements: `j_id0:theForm:thePageBlock:datepicker`

```
<apex:inputField value="{!Service_Order__c.Project_Deadline__c}" 
    html-placeholder="Please allow 8 weeks" 
    id="datepicker" required="true" styleClass="form-control" />
```

[Best Practice for accessing Component IDs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_best_practices_accessing_id.htm)

Use the component reference to get the ID of the above input element from the DOM. Use the jQuery selector by attribute value to find this element and apply the datepicker to it.

```
<script>
    jQuery(function() {
        jQuery("[id='{!$Component.datepicker}']").datepicker();
    });
</script>
```